# What bullet incident is Neil referring to?

Tags: tenet

Neil driving ambulance:

> Protagonist: You knew it was me coming out of that vault. Why didn't
> you say?
>
> Neil: That's a lot of explaining when someone's about to put a **bullet**
> in their own brain.
>
> Protagonist: But afterwards?
>
> Neil: Thing's the same, I knew you'd be okay.

What bullet incident is Neil referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: this answer contains spoilers for the film Tenet.

> Earlier in the film, when Neil and the Protagonist carry out their intricate heist in the art-storage facility at the airport, the Protagonist has an extended fight with an inverted, helmeted man whose face he cannot see. The Protagonist manages to get the other man's gun, but Neil bursts in and stops him from shooting the inverted opponent. The inverted man then gets sucked out the door by the wind from the jet crash outside, and we do not at this point in the film know who he is. But later it becomes clear that the inverted opponent was the Protagonist, and that therefore the Protagonist was fighting himself. We also learn that Neil was aware of this—it's why he stopped the Protagonist from firing during the fight. But he didn't explain what he knew—he just stopped him from shooting—because "That's a lot of explaining when someone's about to put a bullet in their own brain."

> The "bullet incident" you're asking about is therefore the *original* fight earlier in the film between the Protagonist and an inverted opponent who turned out to be himself.